# force float:left divs to dont go to next line

Tags: css, html

lets say I got 20 same divs with float:left property and some width. I want them to be in one line and if they dont fit in screen just to make page scroll horizontally.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPzsV/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's basically how floats work. If you want the described behaviour you can do something else instead, for instance `white-space: nowrap;` on the container and `display: inline-block;` instead of float.

http://jsfiddle.net/NPzsV/3/

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.line {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

One thing to note though: with this approach, newlines/spaces/tabs between the divs will cause a space between them in the rendering.

Comment: Thats it, thanks. I mean, white-space: nowrap; cant be assigned to body to dont destroy all the rest of page structure, only container. But it works. thank you.

Comment: Yes, i just had body there because that was the container in the demo :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on the divs, and add the property `white-space: nowrap` to their parent container.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/akiniv/1/edit

Demo with your fiddle ;) http://jsfiddle.net/NPzsV/4/

Comment: it works, thank you. Only thing i need to say that it needs to add white-space: normal inside content divs to avoid displaying content itself in one line

Comment: Yes, child elements inherit (most) properties of their parents. You can of course override this behaviour as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

set the height to the parent div, and add the property overflow:scroll

```
<div class="parentDiv"> 
    <div class="line">ddd</div>
    <div class="line">ddd</div>
    <div class="line">ddd</div>
     ...
</div>
```

and css:

```
.parentDiv{height:50px; overflow: scroll;}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I've checked it in fiddle and it dont work. And anyway I want page to scroll, not the div.

Answer (score 0):

Set a hard width on the parent element:

```
 body{ width:8000px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NPzsV/1/)

Comment: Who downvoted this? This clearly works. Now maybe not what the OP wants, but if he wants the browser window to scroll this certainly works.

Comment: thanks for try but I want it to look professional, and what if 8000px wouldnt be enought? 80 000? 800 000? And reward for those who have scrolled it all using mouse wheel? :) Just saying.

Comment: I'm very confused. You asked for the "[divs] to be in one line and if they dont fit in screen just to make page scroll horizontally". I'm happy to help but please describe what you actually want.

Comment: This approach has merit in the sense that it works for some of what he wants.